# Highcharts stacking side by side comparison

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I have a chart similar to the Average  Monthly Rainfall demo on the Highcharts web site:  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic

But I want to further split the city data for each month into two sub categories stacked on top of each other [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmcny/7jfcpyo2/3/):

```
$('#Bar1170hMonthly').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Counts'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Counts'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:f} cases</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                //stacking: 'normal',
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        , series: [
            {
            grouping:true,     
            name: '2011: 36',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 19]

        }, {
            name: '2012: 237',
            data: [13, 14, 35, 23, 37, 11, 23, 22, 8, 12, 18, 21]

        }, {
            name: '2013: 360',
            data: [43, 23, 35, 18, 44, 23, 35, 24, 23, 31, 25, 36]

        },
        {
            name: '2014: 112',
            data: [[7, 8], [1, 2], [1, 2], 32, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

        }]

    });
```

For each month for each year I want to split the count into two subcategories a,b and stack on top of each other. Is that possible?

Comment: Not sure what your 'a' and 'b' means, can you do a quick sketch of what your expected output should be?

Comment: 'A', 'B' are just sub category names. Pawel Fus answered the question as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `stacking: "normal"` and for each of stacks set `stack: "id"`, where id's must much between. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/7jfcpyo2/4/

```
 {
     stacking: true,
     stack: 'B',
     name: '2014: 112: stack A',
     data: [6, 1, 1, 32, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

 }, {
     stacking: true,
     stack: 'B',
     name: '2014: 112: stack B',
     data: [9, 2, 2, 32, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

 }
```

The two series above will stack on each other with interfering any other series. You cna have as much stack's as you want to.